# SpringLiquibase: disable migration, just check status

Tags: spring, liquibase

Normally I do liquibase update manually on every environment before upgrading to a new version of the application, for better control.
When the SpringLiquibase bean is initialized within my web application, it applies all pending changesets. However I'd like it to only check status (list pending changesets, incorrect checksums etc.), but not to do update. Is it possible to configure it such a way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not possible AFAIK with available configuration. However you can override the bean `SpringLiquibase` and it's method `afterPropertiesSet()` where everything is executed.